# which data structure to use to store the entries with their time stamp in sorted order

Tags: java, multithreading, collections

I have to implement one scenario in which I need to store large number of entries with their timestamps like "AnyString" with "Timestamp". Now, I have to check periodically for those entries whose timer is going to expire (let's say entries will get expired whose timestamp is more than an hour old). So, in order to keeping them alive, I have to filter out the entries whose timer is going to expire within some time and perform some operations and reinitialize their timestamp. It is multithreaded environment.

In order to do this I am looking for efficient data structure so that when I scan the map to find out whose timer is going to expire, I do not have to traverse entire map. To traverse complete map each time to filter out about to expire entries will have huge performance impact.

I think of using "ConcurrentSkipListMap" in which Comparator can be used to store the entries in the sorted order of timestamps. So that each time I scan the map till the netires having timestamp greater than the required value.

Is there any better way to accomplish this task?
Thanks.

Comment: Treemap or priority queue... Sort ascending on the expiration and the first element is always the next expired time

Comment: Consider using a [`DelayQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html) to handle the timeouts in conjunction with your `Map`

Comment: Is it thread safe?

Answer (score 1):

**Short:**
I suggest you to look into http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/HashedWheelTimer.html - it does what you want.

**Long:**

There is a special kind of structures for this purpose: Timer wheels. [Here](https://blog.acolyer.org/2015/11/23/hashed-and-hierarchical-timing-wheels/)

In short, the idea is the following: you have a large circular array, each element of this array is a list of your objects. Also you have a pointer, which points to some element of the array, and is incremented on each tick. Each element has associated time ranges, which are chosen in a special way. E.g. the whole wheel round is 1s, the array has 1000 elements, then:
0th element is a list of events, that should fire at x.000 - x.001s, 
1st element is a list of events, that should fire at x.001 - x.002s etc.

When you add the new event, you should get the reminder time_when_the_event_should_fire / wheel_period, and this way determine to which element of the array you should add this event.

The pointer will be incremented by 1 on each tick (1 ms), elements are ordered lists - so on each tick you take the element (list), iterate through list items, and if the event should fire at this tick, you fire it, otherwise stop iterating.

Thus you'll get O(1) for all operations, and O(n/wheel_size) on adding new events.